# H.264 Video in MPEG2TS container

Tags: ios5, h.264, mpeg2-ts

I have a hardware codec that encodes video in H.264 (Baseline profile, level 3) which I package into MPEG2 Transport Stream so that I stream it to iDevices (HTTP Live Streaming).

The problem I have is that the video plays only on the more recent iDevices (iPhone 4S/iPhone 5, iPad 2/3) but not on the older iPhones or iPad 1 (there is activity on the screen but nothing even remotely close to actual video).

Further, when it works, the video plays at exactly 1/2 the framerate (30 fps plays as 15 fps).

Safari on Mac Mini or Macbook Pro exhibit no problem whatsoever. VLC & mplayer don't have any problem with the TS files either.

When I package the same video into a MP4 container, all devices play the video properly.

1. Any suggestions on how to debug this problem?
2. Is there any way of getting debug information from iPhone or iPad that would help me figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your level? Do older devices support level 3? If not go to level 1.2 and check

Comment: Older iDevices do support level 3. My video in MP4 container plays fine on all iDevices.